# Making xml key different based upon conditional

Tags: xml, xslt, conditional-statements, transform

I have an xml transform which has a year variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="rptYearVal" select= "//Reports/Report/year" />
```

and some keys to lookup values that I need to use:

```
<xsl:key name="LUState" match="lookupTypes/LookupState/code" use="@id" />
<xsl:key name="LUZip" match="lookupTypes/LookupZipType/code" use="@id" />
```

Now I have a need to specify the key (specifically, the match) based upon a year variable that I set.  So, for the year 2016, the match needs to have a node added:

match="lookupTypes/lookupData/LookupState/code"

I thought I could use a conditional, like so:

```
<xsl:variable name="LookupLocation">
        <xsl:choose>    
                <xsl:when test = "$rptYearVal = '2016'">
                    <xsl:text>lookupTypes/lookupData</xsl:text>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:text>lookupTypes</xsl:text>
                </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable/>
<xsl:key name="LUState" match="$LookupLocation/LookupState/code" use="@id" />
```

but it causes an error.

Can anyone point me in the right direction with this code?

Comment: If this isn't a copy/paste error, `</xsl:variable/>` is definitely a problem.  Remove the second `/`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use a variables inside xsl:key instruction?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404408/is-it-possible-to-use-a-variables-inside-xslkey-instruction)

Comment: If you're getting an error, please post the exact error message. Also state if you're using XSLT 1.0 or2.0.

Comment: AJ- definitely a copy/paste issue in the forum.  Original did not have that extra slash.

Using XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

**There is a good technique to achieve dynamic determination of a key.**

Given this source XML document (as none is provided by the OP):

```
<t>
 <year>2016</year>
 <a>
   <n id="1">an1</n>
   <n id="2">an2</n>
   <n id="3">an3</n>
   <sub>
       <n id="1">aSubn1</n>
       <n id="2">aSubn2</n>
       <n id="3">aSubn3</n>
   </sub>
 </a>
</t>
```

**and this XSLT 1.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kInA" match="a/n" use="@id"/>
 <xsl:key name="kInASub" match="a/sub/n" use="@id"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vStylesheet" select="document('')"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vYear" select="/*/year"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="vKeyName" select=
     "$vStylesheet/*/xsl:key[$vYear = 2016 and @name='kInA']/@name
    | $vStylesheet/*/xsl:key[not($vYear = 2016) and @name='kInASub']/@name "/>

      <xsl:copy-of select="key($vKeyName, '2')"/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**the wanted result (for year 2016) is produced**:

```
<n id="2">an2</n>
```

**Just replace the `<year>` element in the above XML document** so that its string value isn't '2016' -- for example with:

```
 <year>2017</year>
```

**and running the transformation again produces the wanted result, this time**:

```
<n id="2">aSubn2</n>
```

---

What should be your take from this:

**Remember**:

1. One can use a variable for the first argument of the `key()` function
2. A keyname can evan be passed as parameter to any template (and `xsl:function` in XSLT 2.0)

Comment: I see that it's possible to use this solution.  I"ll try it.  Would it also be useful to use $vKeyName in this situation?


`<xsl:for-each select="//lookupTypes/lookupData/FundingStream/code">`

where instead of needing a lookup value, I need to loop through the lookup values, and this lookup location would be different depending upon the year?